# Inserting 0 for empty return on select (sql script running on task scheduler)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a php script running in task schedular every day from 7:45 am to 5 pm. It works great but for the first run it returns nothing since no records have been created yet (records are created by CSR agents taking calls). I have the sql queries running in the script to select, aggregate and insert values into a table and I then create a JSON file from those values. Again, all of this is perfect except that first run.

I've been asked if I can add something to this so that if that first job returns nothing then it would just insert 0's for everything. That way, even if it ran 5 times with no records/calls in the system, there would still be data and the CSR screens would show something. Is there a fairly simple way to do this?

Here's the bulk of the script:

```
    $data = mysqli_query($conn2,
        "SELECT
          case
          when callingpartyno       in (select extension from test.test_users)
          then callingpartyno
          when finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from test.test_users)
          then finallycalledpartyno
          end as extension
            , sum(duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
            , round(sum(duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
            , sum(if(legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
            , sum( case when(legtype1 = 1 and duration > 60) then 1 else 0 end) as credit_for_outbound
            , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1) as total_inbound
            , sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 0) as total_missed
            , sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
            sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
            ,round((sum(if(legtype1 = 2,1,0) and answered = 1))/(sum(if(legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
            sum(if(legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))) * 100,2) as percent_answered
            , now() as time_of_report
            , curdate() as date_of_report
        FROM
            test.session a
            join test.callsummary b
            on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
            where
            date(a.ts) >= curdate()
            and (
            callingpartyno in (select extension from test.test_users
            )
            or  finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from test.test_users
            )
            )
            group by
            extension")  or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));


    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2,
        "INSERT into test.test_totals
              (extension,
              total_talk_time_seconds,
              total_talk_time_minutes,
              total_outbound,
              credit_for_outbound,
              total_inbound,
              missed_calls,
              total_calls,
              percent_answered,
              date_of_report,
                  time_of_report)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON duplicate key
        update
              total_talk_time_seconds = values(total_talk_time_seconds),
              total_talk_time_minutes = values(total_talk_time_minutes),
              total_inbound = values(total_inbound),
              total_outbound = values(total_outbound),
              credit_for_outbound = values(credit_for_outbound),
              missed_calls = values(missed_calls),
              total_calls = values(total_calls),
              percent_answered = values(percent_answered),
              time_of_report = NOW()") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes because sometimes there are zero extension rows (no calls, no extensions, no results)

Change your query so the now() that you use in your select comes from a simple subquery, and left join the rest of your data onto it using an ON clause that is always true

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9b2a1/6 for an example- the subquery giving rise to pseudo table t will always return one row. If Table1 subquery returned one or more rows, the t rows will just repeat identically. If the Table1 subquery returned zero rows, the query as a whole will still have one row. This query can never return zero rows; it's what you need to do to your query to ensure, even if your actual data tables have no rows for a given time period, the overall query will return one row (with a null extension; you can coalesce it to a value if needed)

Edit:

In terms of your query, it would look something more like this:

```
SELECT
  case
    when YOUR_SUBQUERY.callingpartyno in (select extension from test.test_users) then YOUR_SUBQUERY.callingpartyno
    when YOUR_SUBQUERY.finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from test.test_users) then YOUR_SUBQUERY.finallycalledpartyno
  end as extension
  , sum(YOUR_SUBQUERY.duration) as total_talk_time_seconds
  , round(sum(YOUR_SUBQUERY.duration) / 60,2) as total_talk_time_minutes
  , sum(if(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 1,1,0)) as total_outbound
  , sum(case when(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 1 and duration > 60) then 1 else 0 end) as credit_for_outbound
  , sum(if(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 2,1,0) and YOUR_SUBQUERY.answered = 1) as total_inbound
  , sum(if(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 2,1,0) and YOUR_SUBQUERY.answered = 0) as total_missed
  , sum(if(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
  sum(if(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))  as total_calls
  , round((sum(if(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 2,1,0) and YOUR_SUBQUERY.answered = 1))/(sum(if(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound calls
    sum(if(YOUR_SUBQUERY.legtype1 = 2, 1, 0))) * 100,2) as percent_answered
  , TIME_OF_REPORT
  , DATE_OF_REPORT
FROM
  (SELECT NOW() AS TIME_OF_REPORT, CURDATE() AS DATE_OF_REPORT) T
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
      SELECT * FROM
        test.session a
        join test.callsummary b
          on a.notablecallid = b.notablecallid
        where
          date(a.ts) >= curdate() and 
          (
            callingpartyno in (select extension from test.test_users)
            or  
            finallycalledpartyno in (select extension from test.test_users)
          )
  ) YOUR_SUBQUERY
  ON 1=1
  group by
    DATE_OF_REPORT, TIME_OF_REPORT, extension
```

Your sql is essentially lowercase. I added the bits in uppercase. I can't test this, as I know nothing of your table structure and example data, so some debugging from you may be required, but essentially the `(SELECT NOW() AS TIME_OF_REPORT, CURDATE() AS DATE_OF_REPORT) T` should always return one row. The YOUR_SUBQUERY can return 0 to N rows. In the case of 0 rows from YOUR_SUBQUERY, the overall report should still return 1 row, with a time (two, actually, though I'm not sure why you use NOW() which gives a time and date, as well as CURDATE() - the curdate seems redundant as it only gives info that is already given by NOW() but I've left it) and a null extension. All the totals should be 0,though I'm not sure whether e.g. MySQL's IF function, when run like `IF(something_that_is_null = 2, 1, 0)` returns a null (it shouldn't, to my mind; the test should be false to the 0 should be returned and summed as 0). If you do find that all your counts are null rather than 0 on first run, you can COALESCE(logic_doing_sum_here, 0) to turn them from null to 0. If the null extension is bothersome to you, use COALESCE to turn it into some meaningful default value

Comment: Sorry, I think I understand from looking at that fiddle but how would I have to change my existing query exactly? My now() is one of many variables in the select so would I just wrap it in a sub query?

Comment: pretty much, I'll edit the question to give a bit mroe info (wrote the answer from an iphone and it's a proper pain in the arse copying and pasting code on an i

Comment: Ah, thank you! That makes perfect sense, I just wasn't sure how to edit it properly.